# Can I get information about a user with their network ID?

Tags: support, api, users

My [network profile's](http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/%E1%94%95%E1%96%BA%E1%98%8E%E1%95%8A) ID  is `4337810`.

Is there any way to get information about users with their network ID from the API? So stuff like username, location, profile image, etc...?

There doesn't seem to be a `stackexchange` site in http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids, which is why I'm asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `/users/{ids}/associated`

Try it for [your network account](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#ids=4337810&filter=default&run=true)

> Returns all of a user's associated accounts, given their account_ids  in {ids}.
> {ids} can contain up to 100 semicolon delimited ids, to find ids programmatically look for account_id on user objects.
> You can filter the network_users returned by this method with the types parameter. Specify, semicolon delimited, main_site or meta_site to filter by site.
> This method returns a list of network_users.

I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ugz6fhks/) to demonstrate the possible usage and included that as well in the stack snippet found below.

For completeness this is the code:

```js
function load(id) {
    var server = 'http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2',
        path = '/users/' + id + '/associated' ,
        filter = 'filter=!*LCuYQnqAGqQ14Mr';
    $.get(server + path + '?' + filter,  function(data) {
        for(var i=0; i<data.items.length; i++) {
            var u=data.items[i];
            $('#r').append(
                $('<a></a>')
                .text(u.site_name)
                .prop('href', u.site_url+'/users/'+ u.user_id ));
        }
    });
}

$('#load').on('click', function(e) {
    load($('#networkid').val());
    return false;
});
```

```css
a {
      display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label for="networkid">Your SE network ID</label>
    <input id="networkid" type="text" value="4337810" />
    <input id="load" type="button" value="Load" />
</div>
<div id='r'>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm - seems to be it! :) Only problem is that is doesn't give display name, but that's not a problem -- I can find it out by looking at the oldest profile! :) Thanks -- I didn't think of using this!