# Should we enable Stack Snippets?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta

A couple of days ago I [answered](https://stackapps.com/a/6673/18722) a question about the Stack API.

As my answer could be illustrated with a working code example I went ahead to create a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0). To my surprise that feature isn't enabled here, while it is in working order for [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269020/158100). I did fallback to the good old JsFiddle.

Based on a comment from [Haney](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0?noredirect=1#comment273041_270944) it doesn't look like there is a technical reason that this couldn't be enabled here. Leaves me with asking the other users here.

Should we ask the dev team politely to enable Stack Snippets here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put a Snippet in this answer if I knew what to put in one but, thanks to Yaakov, this is now done. :)

Answer (score 8):

> Should we ask the dev team politely to enable Stack Snippets here?

## Yes!

---

It would, primarily, be useful in cases such as your example: support with using the API.

I think people looking for help would always appreciate a minimal example, just to see outputs and how you might go about doing something, and it doesn't take *too* long to make a snippet!

But it could also be used in certain posts such as [The Unofficial Wheel of Blame](https://stackapps.com/q/4357/26088) :)